# How can SWT layout resize (grow/shrink) based on content

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, resize, swt

I have an explorer in my RCP application to which I added an inner composite with a RowLayout to show various category items. When the width of the explorer is resized I want the category items to wrap to new rows and expand the size of their parent composite.

If I initialize my inner composite with defaults, nothing happens, not even wrapping. If I set it to grab vertical space, it takes half the space, leaving the other half for the tree, which is ugly and not what is wanted. If I set hints, I does wrap but the size of its composite never changes, thus hiding the next rows. I tried adding a resize event listener and resizing my inner composite. That allows me to resize it and show all the rows, but it then covers up and hide part of the tree. I tried to do a setLocation and setSize for the tree itself to move/resize it accordingly but to no avail, it doesn't change.

How can this be made to work. What am I missing. Isn't there a simple way to ask for a layout that will use the minimum required height and no more but adjust if needed?

Thanks for your help.

Here the code:

```java
    innerComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    innerComposite.addListener(SWT.Resize, listenerComp);
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().hint(10, 30).applyTo(innerComposite);
    GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(innerComposite);

Listener listenerComp = new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    Widget widget = event.widget;
    Composite comp = (Composite)widget;
    Composite parent = comp.getParent();
    Point parentSize = parent.getSize();
    Point size = comp.computeSize(parentSize.x, SWT.DEFAULT);
    comp.setSize(size);
  }
}
```

And here's an image:

[image]

And after resize (noticing that the 1st row of the tree is covered up):

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Layouts calling `setSize` (or `setBounds`) will mess up the layout that has been setup.

Instead you should call `layout(true)` (or even `layout(true, true)` on the `Composite` which owns both the Tree and your `innerComposite`.

Comment: I tried but without success. Right now I'm trying to either set the hint for the height or the minimum height in the resize listener and then calling layout as you suggested but nothing happens. Am I doing that correctly and at the right place?